# Dynamics365 list view: where is custom javascript located?

Tags: javascript, button, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I need to call custom javascript from custom dialog on the list view.
On list view user click on button (on ribbon). Button starts javascript. Custom javascript create the div dialog with some choices. Every choice has onclick javascript action. But where is my custom javascript code?

In the similar scenario, on form view I can find this cusom javascript as 
`document.getElementById("customScriptsFrame").contentWindow.<my_func>()`

But where is similar location for custom javascript in list view?

Comment: I think you’re using some third party libraries called ESS.Dialog and you have to reach to that support site or some GitHub link

Comment: I finally found it. Custom code in listview is stored in
document.getElementById('contentIFrame0').contentWindow , so my_func() can be  called as document.getElementById('contentIFrame0').contentWindow.my_func();

Comment: you can post your answer and close this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question,

You already have your html div dialog created in a webresource.

Do you already have Ribbon button in place? and Javascript behind it?

If not this is what you need.

There is an plugin in [XRMToolBox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) called [Ribbon Workbench](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/RibbonWorkbench2016/). Use it, and you can [add new button](https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/71374-1-getting-started-with-the-ribbon-workbench) on list view.

On that button command you can add Javascript and function which will be called.

Now inside your javascript you can call your html code or you can directly call another webresource as well.

Comment: No, custom javascript on ribbon button works well. This JS code (called from the ribbon button) will create mentioned dialog and terminates its run. In this created dialog I need  onclick calling of JS function. The problem is that I don't know where to find this function. I was try to add my JS fuction to "global" Xrm object, but this Xrm is probalby on some hidden ifreame. And I have absolutely no idea where.

Comment: when you mention mentioned dialog, do you mean dialog from crm (out of box) or you created dialog (custom) with html?

Comment: JS create custom (non standard) dialog. In technical point of view it is a div added to html document structure. In this div is table and each row has onclick defined.

Comment: again, when you add div to html I believe you create this custom HTML with few lines, completely new and not manipulate CRM HTML? Like create HTML webresource and call it from your javascript?

Comment: JS (simplified)

ESS.Dialog = {

    openDialog: function (html, width, height) {
        var selectDiv = document.createElement('div');
        
        selectDiv.innerHTML = "<span onclick='ESS.Dialog.myJavascript();'> click to run my javascript</span>";

        document.body.appendChild(selectDiv);
    },

    myJavascript: function () {
        alert("Where am I?");

        // remove selectDiv
    }
}

Ribbon button calls ESS.Dialog.openDialog().

But where is ESS.DIalog.myJavascirpt() ?

Answer (score 0):

Right question was "where is stored the custom javascript on listview page". And answer is simple: in iframe named "contentIFrame0". 
So,  right onclick value is "document.getElementById('contentIFrame0').contentWindow.my_func();".